# How can I convert a longtable into enumerate?

Tags: longtable

I have a longtable
[image]
and this is my code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2.0}
\usepackage{longtable}
\setlength\LTleft{15pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}@{}ll}  
first line& 1\\
second line & 2\\
add line& 3\\
add line & 4\\
add line& 5\\
add line & 6\\
add line& 7\\
add line & 8\\
add line& 9\\
add line & 10\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Now I want to number all rows of the longtale from 1 to end. I cannot convert it automatically. I solved with my hand.

```
\begin{enumerate}[\quad 1)]
\item first line \hfill 1
\item second line \hfill 2
\item add line \hfill 3
\item add line \hfill 4 
\item add line \hfill 5
\item add line \hfill 6
\item add line \hfill 7
\item add line \hfill 8
\item add line \hfill 9
\item add line  \hfill 10
\end{enumerate}
```

[image]
How can I conver format longtable as the second picture automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minimising your example to remove irrelevancies, perhaps something like this would work?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2.0}
\usepackage{longtable}
\setlength\LTleft{15pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\newcounter{myconversion}
\setcounter{myconversion}{0}
\newcommand*\convertme{\refstepcounter{myconversion}\themyconversion)\hskip 1.5em}
\begin{document}
  \begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}@{}>{\convertme\arraybackslash}ll}
  first line& 1\\
  second line & 2\\
  add line& 3\\
  add line & 4\\
  add line& 5\\
  add line & 6\\
  add line& 7\\
  add line & 8\\
  add line& 9\\
  add line & 10\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image: enumerated rows]

If you don't want the referencing affected, just change `\refstepcounter` to `\stepcounter`.

To align numbers right:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2.0}
\usepackage{longtable}
\setlength\LTleft{15pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\newcounter{myconversion}
\setcounter{myconversion}{0}
\newcommand*\convertme{\refstepcounter{myconversion}\makebox[1.5em]{\hfill\themyconversion)}\hskip 1em}
\begin{document}
  \begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}@{}>{\convertme\arraybackslash}lr}
  first line& 1\\
  second line & 2\\
  add line& 3\\
  add line & 4\\
  add line& 5\\
  add line & 6\\
  add line& 7\\
  add line & 8\\
  add line& 9\\
  add line & 10\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image: right-aligned numbering]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution, just using a counter for the rows, and the `eqparbox` package, for the alignment of the row numbers.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2.0}
\usepackage{longtable, array}
\setlength\LTleft{15pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcounter{rowno}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{rowno}{0}
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}@{} >{\refstepcounter{rowno}\quad\eqmakebox[R][r]{\therowno)}\hskip\labelsep}ll}
  first line & 1 \\
  second line & 2 \\
  add line & 3 \\
  add line & 4 \\
  add line & 5 \\
  add line & 6 \\
  add line & 7 \\
  add line & 8 \\
  add line & 9 \\
  add line & 10 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]